# How to select the latest rows where each contains one value of all possible values found in a domain table?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ID Username City        RegisterYear
1  User1    New York    1990
2  User2    San Diego   2008
3  User3    Chicago     2009
4  User4    Los Angeles 1994
5  User5    San Diego   2004
```

Domain Table

```
ID  City
1   New York
2   San Diego
3   Los Angeles
4   Chicago
```

In this example the query would return:

```
User1
User2
User3
user4
```

Comment: You need to post your relevant database schema, for `User` and `City` we need to know what primary keys exist and what foreign keys exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you need to replace "City" in the first table with the ID column of the domain table. The "City" is not the primary key.

After that:

```
SELECT u.username
FROM   users u,
       domain d
WHERE  d.id = u.cityid
       AND u.registeryear = (SELECT MAX(u2.registeryear)
                             FROM   users u2
                             WHERE  u2.cityid = u.cityid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question doesn't provide an awful lot of detail, I have used some of the assumption that syrion made plus also decided that the city name will be unique to make things easier.

```
select max(u.username) keep (dense_rank last order by registeryear) as username
from 
  domain d
  left outer join users u on (d.city = u.city)
group by d.city
```